# $\mathbb{R}$-linear function could be uniquely written as $f(z)=\alpha z + \beta \bar{z}$, with $\alpha$, $\beta$ $\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

With the identification $\mathbb{C} \equiv \mathbb{R^2}$ (usual isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$, note by $g : \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{C}$), show that each $\mathbb{R}$-linear function could be uniquely written as $g \circ f(z)=\alpha z + \beta \bar{z}$, with $\alpha$, $\beta$ $\in \mathbb{C}$.

A $\mathbb{R}$-linear function means $f(z)=(ax-by,ay+bx)=$ $\begin{bmatrix}a & -b\\a & b \end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix}$ for $z=(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$

In using the definition of a $\mathbb{R}$-linear function, I can almost find good values $\alpha$, $\beta$ $\in \mathbb{C}$. However, "*almost*" is not sufficient.

Is anyone could give me a hint on how to find the right values?

Comment: Do you mind providing a definition for $\mathbb{R}$-linear function?

Comment: if $\mathbb{R}$-linear means $f(x+iy) = ax + b i y$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ then $f(z) = a(z+\bar{z})/2 +  i b (z-\bar{z})/2$ so $\alpha = a/2 + ib/2$ and $\beta = a/2 - ib/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Try computing

$$\frac{f(z)+\overline{f(z)}}{z+\overline{z}} $$

and

$$\frac{f(z)-\overline{f(z)}}{z-\overline{z}} $$

to obtain an easy system of equations you can solve for $\alpha,\beta$.

Comment: Could you complete the answer to this question? :)