# $\frac{f(z)+\overline{f(z)}}{z+\overline{z}} $ and $\frac{f(z)-\overline{f(z)}}{z-\overline{z}} $ - System of equations

Tags: complex-analysis

With the identification $\mathbb{R}^2 \equiv \mathbb{C}$, show that each function $\mathbb{R}$-linear $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ could be set uniquely as $f(z)= \alpha z +  \beta \bar{z}$, where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$.

I know that a $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ needs to fulfill $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f(ax) = af(x)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in \mathbb{C}$. However, I can not put it into the desired shape. Does someone could give me his help at this level?

So we have a function such that $f(ax+by) = af(x)+bf(y)$ avec $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$, and I think we can obtain a system of equations with trying to compute

$$\frac{f(z)+\overline{f(z)}}{z+\overline{z}} $$

and

$$\frac{f(z)-\overline{f(z)}}{z-\overline{z}} $$

Comment: Is this a follow-up of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616479/mathbbr-linear-function-could-be-uniquely-written-as-fz-alpha-z-beta?

Comment: Ok, but I need a bit more details, could you explain to me? I don't know what is the form of $f(z)$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650324/simple-linear-map-question.